# react openlayers popup offsetWidth issue

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, components, openlayers

I am trying to implement openlayers popup in react.
It is implemented in plain js here: [https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Here is my code:

```
import {createRef, useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import './Map.css';

import Map from '../node_modules/ol/Map.js';
import Overlay from '../node_modules/ol/Overlay.js';
import TileLayer from '../node_modules/ol/layer/Tile.js';
import View from '../node_modules/ol/View.js';
import XYZ from '../node_modules/ol/source/XYZ.js';
import {toLonLat} from '../node_modules/ol/proj.js';
import {toStringHDMS} from '../node_modules/ol/coordinate.js';

const MapExample = () => {
    const [popupContent, setPopupContent] = useState('');
    const containerRef = createRef();
    const contentRef = createRef();
    const closerRef = createRef();
    
    const key = 'CvOgKFhRDDHIDOwAPhLI';

    const overlay = new Overlay({
        element: containerRef.current,
        autoPan: {
            animation: {
                duration: 250,
            },
        },
    });
    
    const handleCloser = () => {
        overlay.setPosition(undefined);
        closerRef.current.blur();
        return false;
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const map = new Map({
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new XYZ({
                        url: 'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=' + key,
                        tileSize: 512,
                    }),
                }),
            ],
            overlays: [overlay],
            target: 'map',
            view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2,
            }),
        });


        map.on('singleclick', (evt) => {
            const coordinate = evt.coordinate;
            const hdms = toStringHDMS(toLonLat(coordinate));

            setPopupContent('You clicked here: ' + hdms)
            overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
        });
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div id="map" className="map"></div>
            <div ref={containerRef} className="ol-popup">
                <a ref={closerRef} href="#" className="ol-popup-closer" onClick={handleCloser}></a>
                <div ref={contentRef}>{popupContent}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MapExample;
```

I've got an issue with offset width:
[picture with an issue: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'offsetWidth')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJW9g.png) The problem is popup appears on the left bottom corner, not in the clicked place of the map.

How I understand this bug appears, because popup's properties are null. I tried to fix this bug, but could not find a working solution. Will be really grateful for any help )))

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of React lifecycle issues in your code. Do not use `createRef` in functional components as it will create a new reference at every render - while the `useEffect` code will run only once. This means that the overlay will lose its connection to the map - especially since you create a new `Overlay` at each render.

Also I strongly advise you to not use `useEffect` to create Openlayers components - the reasons are very subtle - but the main problem is that your components won't be reusable or even rerendable.

As the author of [`rlayers`](https://github.com/mmomtchev/rlayers) I can tell you that proper wrapping of Openlayers components is not easy - you must manually manage the components' lifecycle. This works best with class-based components on which you should override all lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

put the containerRef in the dependency argument for the useEffect to make sure it is loaded when code is ran. This should solve your issue